# Tensorflow memory leak in every iteration

Tags: tensorflow, memory-leaks

I'm trying to find out why the code below occurs a huge memory leak during iteration by iteration. Here's the whole code.

```
def train_network(file_folder, file_list, hm_epochs, batch_size):    
    num_files = len(file_list)

    with g.as_default():

        input_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 40, 200, 300, 3])
        y1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
        y2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

        class_logit, highlight_logit = convolutional_neural_network(input_image)

        class_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=class_logit, labels=y1))
        highlight_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=highlight_logit, labels=y2))

        optimizer1 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-6).minimize(class_loss, centered=True)
        optimizer2 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-7).minimize(highlight_loss, centered=True)

        #### Saving Network ####
        with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
            saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep = 3)
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            for epoch in xrange(hm_epochs):
                epoch_loss = 0

                for idx in xrange(num_files):
                    _file = file_folder + '/' + file_list[idx]
                    X_total, Y1_class, Y2_score = read_as_batch(_file)
                    n_batch = int(X_total.shape[0]/batch_size)
                    for i in xrange(n_batch):

                        batch_X = get_batch_piece(X_total, batch_size, i)
                        batch_Y1 = get_batch_piece(Y1_class, batch_size, i)
                        batch_Y2 = get_batch_piece(Y2_score, batch_size, i)

                        _, _, a, b, c, d = sess.run([optimizer1, optimizer2, class_loss, highlight_loss, tf.gather(class_logit, 0), tf.gather(highlight_logit, 0)], feed_dict={input_image: batch_X, y1: batch_Y1, y2: batch_Y2})
                        result = float(a) + float(b)
                        del a, b, batch_X, batch_Y1, batch_Y2

                        epoch_loss += result

                        del c, d
                        gc.collect()
                ckpt_path = saver.save(sess, "saved/train", epoch)
```

And the below is memory profiler result. I figured out the functions **read_as_batch** and **get_batch_piece** are not the reason of the memory leaking by several experiments.

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
35  215.758 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
36                             def train_network(file_folder, file_list, hm_epochs, batch_size):
37                                 
38  215.758 MiB    0.000 MiB       num_files = len(file_list)                             
44  215.758 MiB    0.000 MiB       with g.as_default():
45                             
46  216.477 MiB    0.719 MiB           input_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 40, 200, 300, 3])
47  216.477 MiB    0.000 MiB           y1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
48  216.477 MiB    0.000 MiB           y2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
49                             
50  220.199 MiB    3.723 MiB           class_logit, highlight_logit = convolutional_neural_network(input_image)
51                             
52  220.711 MiB    0.512 MiB           class_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=class_logit, labels=y1))                          
54  220.953 MiB    0.242 MiB           highlight_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=highlight_logit, labels=y2))
55                             
56  227.562 MiB    6.609 MiB           optimizer1 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-6).minimize(class_loss)
57  234.062 MiB    6.500 MiB           optimizer2 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-7).minimize(highlight_loss)
58                             
59                                     #### Saving Network ####
60  660.691 MiB  426.629 MiB           with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
62  666.848 MiB    6.156 MiB               saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep = 3)
63 1183.676 MiB  516.828 MiB               sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
67 1642.145 MiB  458.469 MiB               for epoch in xrange(hm_epochs):
68 1642.145 MiB    0.000 MiB                   epoch_loss = 0
69 1642.145 MiB    0.000 MiB                   file_list_ = iter(file_list)
71                                             #for idx in xrange(num_files):
74 1642.145 MiB    0.000 MiB                   _file = file_folder + '/' + file_list_.next()
77 1779.477 MiB  137.332 MiB                   data = np.load(_file)
78                                             # Batch Data Generation
79 1916.629 MiB  137.152 MiB                   X_total = np.array([data[0][0][0], data[0][0][1], ...])
81                                             # Class, Score Data Fetching
82 1916.629 MiB    0.000 MiB                   Y1_class = data[0][1][0]
83 1916.629 MiB    0.000 MiB                   Y2_score = data[0][2][0]
85 1916.629 MiB    0.000 MiB                   batch_X = get_batch_piece(X_total, 1, 1)
86 1916.629 MiB    0.000 MiB                   batch_Y1 = get_batch_piece(Y1_class, 1, 1)
87 1916.629 MiB    0.000 MiB                   batch_Y2 = get_batch_piece(Y2_score, 1, 1)
88 1916.805 MiB    0.176 MiB                   _ = sess.run([optimizer1], feed_dict={input_image: batch_X, y1: batch_Y1, y2: batch_Y2})
89                             
90 1642.145 MiB -274.660 MiB                   del data, X_total, Y1_class, Y2_score, batch_X, batch_Y1, batch_Y2, optimizer1
```

To improve readability, I shorten the code. Even the memory profiling result is little bit different to the original code, it is the same and occurs the same problem (memory leaking). **The fact is when I remove the *sess.run([optimizer1], ...)*, the code does not leak the memory even the epoch is over 100. However, the case I run the session, the memory usage gets bigger and bigger so I cannot do train anymore even with the epoch 5.**

I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is you create **new** tensorflow operations on every session call.

Move these two out of for loop `tf.gather(class_logit, 0), tf.gather(highlight_logit, 0)`, and problem should gone.

Comment: It works!! Thank you very very much.
I have one more question. Is there any other way to check the logit changes during the training?

Comment: Yeah, you could either print the value or use tensorboard.

Comment: Yeeeaah. I will try. Thank you again :)

Comment: @DmitriyDanevskiy could you elaborate? What if the ops each iteration were named (like `my_op = tf.concat(...)`), wouldn't that overwrite the variable in Python and activate the garbage collector? Or maybe you are saying Tensorflow at a lower-level won't garbage collect those objects each loop iteration?

Comment: @lollercoaster This would have no effect since all tensorflow ops are parts of some tf.Graph object.

Comment: Calling `tf.gather` or any other tensorflow graph ops doesn't compute the values immediately, it instead add an op to the current compute graph and the values are computed during during `sess.run`. What's happening here is that you are adding an op to the graph at every iteration, thus increasing the amount of memory used. To achieve what you want here, move `tf.gather`  outside the loop to something like `cl = tf.gather (...)` and then get them with ` ..., x = sess.run([ ..., cl])`